# How can I have global alt tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have many images. All images have an `alt` tag; something like alt="img1"...

Is there any change hold value of the tag in variable? Something like

```
<script>
    const altVariable="img";
</script>
```

and then in HTML use this variable like `alt="<script>altVariable</script>"`?

I know the line above doesn't work like this.

Comment: How do you want to write the alt tag to the image, is it just some default static text? In which case it would be easy to write a method to do this (I have just done something similar at work). If somehow you want a dynamic alt tag per image that will require more work but it depends what you want to achieve

Comment: I want find best key words for SEO and i want write it from 1 file. First idea was use PHP but PHP is blocked for users for safety. I wanna do same thing for <a href> titles and also image titles. In the past it happened i had to change manually over 12000 titles and alts

Comment: if you care about SEO then you shoudn't do it with javascript. Search engines do not execute scripts when crawling pages, they exptect the `alt` attribute to be included in your markup (meaning you should do it server-side, like you said, in PHP)

Comment: ou damn u saved me maybe tons of hours. Gonna do research about that. Didnt realise how Search engines work. Ty!

Comment: Yes if you can do it via php or another backend method this is much more preferable. However I recently wrote a fallback in JS which finds empty img alt tags and replaces them. This does actually improve performance (but not SEO).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with JavaScript if you want to set all images with the same alt.

```
const altVariable="img";
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => img.alt = altVariable);
```

Comment: Hello, ive pasted ur code to <script> tags but i dont see the alt in inspect elements. I have just basic image atm. <img class="img__left" src="img1.jpg"> in index.html

Comment: they won't appear on source